# Regular expression for not more than one occurance of consecutive characters

Tags: regex, grep

I'm looking for regular expression that will match only if 2 consecutive characters occur in string once.

for example:

- 1123456 - match
- 1122345 - not match
- 1121125 - not match
- 1234567 - not match
- 1112345 - not match

currently have this regex: ([0-9])\1{1,} but it matches 1122345 as well which is not what i need

Comment: Hi! Do you have any idea of how you could tackle the problem? We value attempts in StackOverflow.

Comment: i am trying but i'm not really strong in regex. I have this one: ([0-9])\1{1,} but it matches to 1122 as well

Comment: So a more precise statement of your problem is: you must only match strings where there is exactly one occurrence of exactly two identical consecutive characters”?

Comment: @barny yes, your statement matches my problem

Comment: I think you’ll have to write code to first match strings with two repeated characters, then check that there isn’t another repeat of two characters after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk does it, if you have minimal awk (`mawk`) or GNU awk (`gawk`):

```
awk -F "" '
{
    d=0
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
        if ($i==$(i+1)) d++
    }
    if (d==1) print
}' file
```

Setting the field to empty string (`""`) you can read each line character-wise! If character `i` equals character `i+1`, then increment `d`. If `d==1`, the string is printed.

From your sample:

```
$ cat file
1123456
1122345
1121125
1234567
1112345
```

It outputs:

```
1123456
```

---

**Important remark:**

GNU awk manual says the use of empty string as field separator is a "dark corner", meaning that it is not standard and some implementations may handle it differently. If you want to be sure that it will work with any awk, go for

```
awk '
{
    d=0
    n=split($0,ch,"")
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        if (ch[i]==ch[i+1]) d++
    }
    if (d==1) print
}' file
```

It passed the `gawk --posix` test and yields the same result.

Comment: thanks. this is awesome, awk works for me in this case too :)

Comment: @k0d3r1s Glad to help! If it solves your problem, consider accepting it :)